Next 14 session UUID generating
I want to add a session id in cookies, I tried using multiple approach but none of them worked correctly
I tried api, it works only if I visited link in browser, if I use fetch function for api it will only generate session id but it will not store it in cookies
//api/session/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  // Parse cookies from the request headers
  const cookieHeader = request.headers.get('cookie') || '';
  const cookies = Object.fromEntries(
    cookieHeader.split('; ').map(cookie => {
      const [name, value] = cookie.split('=');
      return [name, value];
    })
  );

  // Check if the session ID already exists
  let sessionId = cookies['sessionId'];

  if (sessionId) {
    console.log('Session ID exists:', sessionId);
    return NextResponse.json({ sessionId, message: 'Session ID already exists' });
  }

  // If no session ID, generate a new one
  sessionId = uuidv4();
  console.log('Generated new Session ID:', sessionId);

  const response = NextResponse.json({
    sessionId,
    message: 'New session ID created',
  });

  // Set the session ID in the cookies
  response.cookies.set('sessionId', sessionId, {
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 7 days
    path: '/', // Accessible on all routes
    httpOnly: true, // Prevents JavaScript access
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false, // HTTPS in production
    sameSite: 'lax', // Prevent CSRF attacks
  });

  return response;
}



I tried using middleware.ts file but I didn’t manage to make it work
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("Middleware executed for:", request.nextUrl.pathname);

  const sessionId = request.cookies.get("sessionId");

  if (!sessionId) {
    const newSessionId = uuidv4();
    console.log("Generated new Session ID:", newSessionId);

    const response = NextResponse.next();
    response.cookies.set("sessionId", newSessionId, {
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      path: "/",
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: "lax",
    });

    return response;
  }

  console.log("Session ID exists:", sessionId);
  return NextResponse.next();
}


I want to generate session in the layout.tsx which will be main layout for must of pages I need which require session id
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Navbar from '@/components/navbar';
import Footer from "@/components/footer_section";
import { connectToMongoDB } from "@/lib/mongodb";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Eilaji",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  connectToMongoDB()
  
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        <Footer/>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}



